# How to make HAProxy's SSL redirect and path rewrite (with reqrep) work at the same time?

Tags: ssl, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I need to deploy different apps on the same domain, thus I've set up the `backend` to rewrite URL with `reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)appA[/]?(.*)     \1\2`. It works when I only deploy the HTTP or HTTPS version of the app.

However, if I try to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, it doesn't work. The problem is that HAProxy has already rewritten the URL and stripped out the `/appA` part before the redirection. Thus if I try to visit `http://myserver.com/appA`, the page `https://myserver.com` will eventually be requested instead of `https://myserver.com/appA`.

I can't put the redirect rule before the reqrep rule as it seems that HAProxy must process all the rewrites before the redirects.

What can I do to make my configuration work as I intended? This should be obvious but I can't seem to find a relevant answer online.

My configuration:

```
frontend http_front
  bind *:80
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
  acl appA_url url_beg /appA
  use_backend appA if appA_url

frontend https_front
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/myserver.com.pem
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  acl appA_url url_beg /appA
  use_backend appA if appA_url

backend appA
  reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)appA[/]?(.*)     \1\2
  redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
  balance roundrobin
  server web1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http-request` directives, which are processed in declararion order.  They are also newer features, and usually cleaner, more intuitive, more flexible, and more internally efficient than `reqxxx`.

```
http-request redirect scheme https if ! { ssl_fc }
http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/appA/,/)]
```

See [`http-request`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-http-request).  Requires 1.6 or later, where the `regsub()` converter is available.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/9-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/ though I didn't realize the use of `regsub`. Also, it should be `regsub(^/appA,/)`, i.e. without the second slash in the path.

Comment: You are right, my solution doesn't handle the bare value without a trailing slash, but hours won't be quite right either, because then `/appA/foo` becomes `//foo`.

Comment: The most correct solution would actually be to redirect the exact path `/appA` to append the slash to make it `/appA/`, because otherwise, all relative paths are off-by-one, since `/appA` + `./foo` is resolved as `/foo` while `/appA/` + `./foo` is resolved as `/appA/foo`.  Paths can become a little delicate when the back-end doesn't know the actual path as understood by the browser.

Comment: *yours, not "hours"

Comment: That makes sense. Currently the double slash doesn't seem to break my app but I know one shouldn't rely on this behavior. Changing the backend routing rules so that `/appA/` is prefixed to every route, instead of trying to use HAProxy rewrite to create a discrepency between the browser and the backend seems to be a solution in this case then.

Comment: I think another solution is to specify the trailing `/` in the regex as optional with `^/appA/?`. So that whether it is present or not, one `/` is always substituted in the place of the original path. That should cover both scenarios.

Comment: `regsub()` is limited by some limitations in the configuration parser, so the really right thing of matching something like `^/appA(/|$)` isn't possible...  but `%[path,regsub(^/appA$,/),regsub(^/appA/,/)]` seems like a precise solution.